# How to clean output screen after 1minute

Tags: xcode

I generated randomly an matrix in matlab now I need a MATLAB command to clean output from screen after 1minute visualization before to continue...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on Stack Overflow must be written in English.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You don't need a custom reason for that, you can vote to close it as unclear. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/3151675

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
clc
```

Documentation:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clc.html

You should translate your question into entglish..